# Psexec vs Powershell

Tags: file-upload, local, remote-access, profile, psexec

Hoping someone will be able to help with my speed bump. I'll explain the scenario below and then what I'm trying to do for a better understanding.

Basically I'm needing to copy a local file onto remote computers. Now I have a list of computers requiring the file. I know psexec can do this but I'm needing to use the admin account to connect to the machine and copy the file and then run the file under the user profile who is logged in.

I have done some research and see that Powershell can do it albeit with a lot of scripting.

Is there perhaps another way of doing this that I might have missed?

Thanks and sorry for the lengthy post.

Comment: Please add some relevant tags, and describe your efforts so far.

Comment: Tried doing Psexec and running the command under the administrator account but it didn't work. Basically the file runs, a process is started but nothing happens. But if I remote to the machine and run the file that way, it works. So guessing it is something with psexec and the way it runs files.

Also tried copying the file to the computer and running psexec with the remote cmd, but after running the file, nothing happens there either.

So running the file locally works but using psexec with admin account, even though it starts the file, it doesn't complete the operation.